# jquery [tabs] open and close

Tags: jquery, html

this is my first question on Stack Overflow.
Need some help with tabs. Now when i click one of h3 tags i open tab content, but i wanna close it on next click in h3.

Apologize for my bad english skills, hope you all understand what i meant.

this is my html:

```
             <div class="sub-aside">
                <h3 class="sub-category" data-tab="tab-1">shopping communities</h3>
                <ul class="first-side-menu drop-content sub-content" id="tab-1">
                    <li><a href="#">Home Goods</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cooking</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-aside">
                <h3 class="sub-category"  data-tab="tab-2">life events</h3>
                <ul class="drop-content sub-content" id="tab-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Anniversary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Back to school</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and my jquery code:

```
$(".sub-category").on('click', function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('.sub-category').removeClass('content-active');
        $('.sub-content').removeClass('content-active');

        $(this).addClass('content-active');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('content-active');

        $('.sub-category').toggleClass('content-active');
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toggle`.

```
$(".sub-category").on('click', function () {
 $(this).next('ul').toggle();       
})
```

```js
$(".sub-category").on('click', function () {
 //Toggle particular element 
 $(this).next('ul').toggle();      
 //Hide all the elements not the clicked one  
 $(".sub-category").next('ul').not($(this).next('ul')).hide(); 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-aside">
                <h3 class="sub-category" data-tab="tab-1">shopping communities</h3>
                <ul class="first-side-menu drop-content sub-content" id="tab-1">
                    <li><a href="#">Home Goods</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cooking</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-aside">
                <h3 class="sub-category"  data-tab="tab-2">life events</h3>
                <ul class="drop-content sub-content" id="tab-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Anniversary</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Back to school</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Would be so kind and implement this into my js?

Comment: ok, but i wanna get the effect: open one tab, and close another open tab. How to do this?

Comment: So when you see one tab it should hide all other open tabs, right ?

Comment: exactly @Loading :)

Comment: Google is the best option, but you can go to jquery website try to implement as much as demo you can..see the console everytime..that's the way you will rock man.

Comment: Hi again, to the jquery above i wanna add highlight clicked element with some other color for example

Comment: You can do it by using .css, `$(this).css('color', 'red)`  something like that.

Comment: i need some kind of if statement to disable highlight color when i click another link?

Answer (score 2):

Use **slideToggle** for better effect

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sub-category").on('click', function () {
   $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();       
  })
});
```

**Html**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="sub-aside">
            <h3 class="sub-category" data-tab="tab-1">shopping communities</h3>
            <ul class="first-side-menu drop-content sub-content" id="tab-1">
                <li><a href="#">Home Goods</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cooking</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-aside">
            <h3 class="sub-category"  data-tab="tab-2">life events</h3>
            <ul class="drop-content sub-content" id="tab-2">
                <li><a href="#">Anniversary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Back to school</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

check it on [JsFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/63/)